# MongoDB $in not only one result in case of repeated elements

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I need to get the users whose ids are contained in an array. For this i'm using the $in operator, however being this inside an aggregate operation, i'd like to get back a specific user all the time it's id is present in the array, not just one. For example:

```
The ids array is A=[a,b,c,b] and U(x) is user with id x
with users.find({_id:{$in:A}}) i get these users as result: U(a),U(b),U(c)
instead i'd like to get back the result: U(a),U(b),U(c),U(b)
```

so get the user back every time it's id appears.

I understand that $in is working as expected but does anyone have an idea on how can i achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: An `$in` query will return _all_ matching documents, not just the first one of each; so it should already be doing what you want.

Comment: an _id has a unique index on it so it's not possible to have multiple documents with the same _id value in a collection.  I suspect what you want is for that same document to be returned twice if the _id is mentioned twice in the $in [array].

Comment: @JohnnyHK: actually not, works as i described and it's quite aligned with the meaning of the word "in" as a matter of facts

Comment: @AsyaKamsky:that's exactly what i want to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible using a MongoDB query.

MongoDB's query engine iterates over the documents in a collection (or over an index if there's a useful one) and returns to you any documents that match your query, in the order it finds them. Whether `b` appears once, twice, or a hundred times in your query makes no difference: the document with `_id` of `b` matches the query and is returned once, when MongoDB finds it.

You can do a post-processing step in your programming language to repeat documents as many times as you want.

Comment: I thought the same but as last resort i asked here :D